# I have a geom_bar that I want to organize but cannot seem to figure out how

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of a data I'm working on but can't seem to organize the bin size of my data

```
vgsales %>% 
  ggplot(aes(User_Score)) +
  geom_bar()
```

The bins are all crowded and not sure how to make them look nicer:

[image: The bins are all crowded and not sure how to make them look nicer.]

I would like them to range from 1-10 but with a bin size of 0.5. Unsure how to do that. I'm a beginner and in need of help.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. You're referring to bin sizes, which implies a histogram, but then drawing a bar plot. I'm going to guess that you've got data in a type you're not expecting (maybe a factor?), but without any data, guessing is the best anybody can do

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears that `User_Score` is a `factor` or `character`, not `numeric`. Second, it looks like you may need `geom_histogram()` rather than `geom_bar`.

You could try the following to see if they make any differences:

```
vgsales %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(as.character(User_Score))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
  geom_bar()
```

or

```
vgsales %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(as.character(User_Score))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram()
```